# hector_heat_detection missing dependency?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the hector_heat_detection dependencies, is "thermaleye_msgs" , but i couldn't find it anywhere!

at first i thought it's a part of [thermalvis](http://wiki.ros.org/thermalvis), but it was not!

any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141081/hector_heat_detection-missing-dependency?/) by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 717 on 2014-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, that package is indeed missing. If you want to proceed, the simplest way to fix things might be to just create a thermaleye_msgs package yourself and putting this one msg definition into it:

Mapping.msg:

```
float64 minTemp
float64 maxTemp
```

As fixing this properly requires some internal re-organization of our repos, it might take a little time.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0